# ADO.Net retrieving autoincrement values for MS Access database in strongly typed DataSets

Tags: c#, ms-access, ado.net, auto-increment

I write a database client application in C# using MS Access as a DB server.

Users insert new rows using a `DataGridView`. I need to retrieve autoincrement values of the inserted rows on

```
this.MyTableTableAdapter.Update(MyDataSet.MyTable)
```

operation.

I can't use

```
this.MyTableTableAdapter.Fill(MyDataSet.MyTable);
```

after update operation to refresh the entire table, because the position of required inserted record is lost.

So I read `learn.microsoft.com`, section "Retrieving Identity or Autonumber Values":

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/data/adonet/retrieving-identity-or-autonumber-values

to understand how to do it.

They write a vague description about it:

> Some database engines, such as the Microsoft Access Jet database engine, do not support output parameters and cannot process multiple statements in a single batch. When working with the Jet database engine, you can retrieve the new AutoNumber value generated for an inserted row by executing a separate SELECT command in an event handler for the RowUpdated event of the DataAdapter.

I also found a code that must be performed in the event

https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/adonet-cookbook/0596004397/ch04s04.html

```
private void OnRowUpdated(object Sender, OleDbRowUpdatedEventArgs args)
{
    // Retrieve autonumber value for inserts only.
    if(args.StatementType == StatementType.Insert)
    {
        // SQL command to retrieve the identity value created
        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand("SELECT @@IDENTITY", da.SelectCommand.Connection);

        // Store the new identity value to the CategoryID in the table.
        args.Row[CATEGORYID_FIELD] = (int)cmd.ExecuteScalar( );
    }
}
```

The problem is that VS IDE designer creates strongly typed DataSet without external visibility of DataAdapter object.

It creates TableAdapter that is inherited from Component but not from DataAdapter.

And although it creates a real DataAdapter inside the myTableTableAdapter class, it have protected level.

```
protected internal global::System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter Adapter
```

So I can't add any event to the Adapter outside the class myTableTableAdapter.

I assume that the code should be written inside the myTableTableAdapter class 
but the code of this class is autogenerated, and file have next comment

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
// <auto-generated>
//     This code was generated by a tool.
//     Runtime Version:4.0.30319.42000
//
//     Changes to this file may cause incorrect behavior and will be lost if
//     the code is regenerated.
// </auto-generated>
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

So my custom code could be lost if I add any changes.

So my question is - How to add RowUpdated event for the DataAdapter in strongly typed DataSets?

Comment: It's `protected internal` which means `protected` OR `internal`. You should be able to access the `internal` field so long as it's in the same project (assembly) as the code you are attempting to access it from

Comment: Yes.
      myTable.Adapter.RowUpdated += OnRowUpdated;
works. 
Thank you.

Comment: Often times auto-generated code is done inside of a `partial` class. If that is the case here, you could add the relevant code in another file but have it still be within the same class. I don't know off hand if that is the case here. But if it is, that's probably the better approach.

Comment: Yes. There are two files: MyDataSet.Designer.cs and MyDataSet.cs

I can write code in MyDataSet.cs

  public partial class MyTableTableAdapter : global::System.ComponentModel.Component
  {
    private void MyMethod()
    {
      Adapter.RowUpdated += OnUserRowUpdated;
    }
  }

But how (from where) to make MyMethod() to be called?

private void InitAdapter() {
is in the MyDataSet.Designer.cs file.

Answer (score 0):

"DataSet, DataTables, and DataRow objects created by the Typed DataSet can be extended through the use of partial classes."

For more on partial classes see 'step 3' here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/data-access/introduction/creating-a-business-logic-layer-vb#step-3-adding-field-level-validation-to-the-datarow-classes.

The example above uses ColumnChanging but i'm sure you could extend RowUpdated.

Comment: Hello

I can not use your advice.

DataTable.BeginInit() is virtual and it is goot but,

RowUpdated is an event of OleDbDataAdapter but I don't have access to Adapter from inside of DataTable.BeginInit method.

Comment: There are class

public partial class myTableTableAdapter : global::System.ComponentModel.Component {
        protected internal global::System.Data.OleDb.OleDbDataAdapter Adapter {
        }
}

it is the class in which the Adapter property resides and the Adapter.RowUpdated event is available.

but myTableTableAdapter doesn't have BeginInit() method or any other virtual method suitable for use.

Comment: On normally it is necessary to write in the the constructor of myTableTableAdapter class,
but the constructor is already described in the auto-generated file - MyDataSet.Designer.cs.
So I can not write another constructor in MyDataSet.cs.